# Files that have at most two ‘a’ characters in their full path

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to figure out how to find files that have at most two 'a' characters in their full path with AWK.

The following is what I've come up so far but it's not doing the job.

```
BEGIN{}

{
if( match( $1, ".*[a].*[a].*[^a]+" ) )
print $1
}

END{}
```

It reads the files names with their full paths from a file called "data" created separately via the following command.

```
find / -name '*'
```

What should I modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three errors.

1. You need to include the start-of-line and end-of-line patterns `^` and `$` otherwise an arbitrary prefix or suffix may contain some `a`s.
2. You need to make the occurrences of `a` optional, by using parenthesis and `?`.
3. `.*` can contain `a` so you need to use `[^a]` to match the non-a characters.

The result would be a regular expression like:

```
^([^a]*a)?([^a]*a)?[^a]*$
```

---

**Edit:**

As Ed points out in the comments below [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808425/310165), if you pass the `--re-interval` flag to Awk, you can use intervals.

The expression would then be:

```
^([^a]*a){0,2}[^a]*$
```

This allows us say we want to find between 0 and 2 `a`s.

Comment: --re-interval is only needed with older versions of GNU awk. newer gawk versions have it enabled by default, as do some other awks while for yet other awks it's just not available at all.

Answer (score 6):

The following is judged too short to be an answer on its own, but it's all I meant to write:

```
^[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*)?)?$
```

By the way, you don't need `awk`. `grep -E` would work fine.

But now that I think of it, if you are going to use awk, the following is even simpler:

```
awk '!/a.*a.*a/'
```

Comment: Yeap, that did the trick. Thanks a lot. :) By the way, the assignment of mine required that I use awk.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is this:

```
awk '!/(.*a){3}/' file
```

or either of these if your awk doesn't support RE intervals:

```
awk 'gsub(/a/,"&") < 3' file
awk 'split($0,x,/a/) < 3' file
```

so in either case if you want to test for fewer than 17 "a"s you just change 3 to 17 (for example):

```
awk '!/(.*a){17}/' file
```

rather than writing:

```
awk '^[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*(a[^a]*)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$'
```

or similar.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Is there a way to match "2 or fewer" instances in the braces notation? In other words, why can't we do `^([^a]*a){0,2}[^a]*$`?

Comment: @Geoff that looks like it'd be correct. A bit harder to get the mind around than the not-3-or-more RE though!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, so I was hoping you'd know. I couldn't find an "X or fewer" expression in my Googling.

Comment: It works for me with gawk 4.0.0 as `awk '/^([^a]*a){0,2}[^a]*$/'`. Found lines with zero, 1, and 2 "a"s and excluded lines with 3 or more. Maybe you're using an older gawk and need to add the --re-interval flag?

Comment: intervals are really neat but this was an assignment. It will be executed normally. But if ever I need something like this it will be really helpful. Thanks a lot Ed.